# javascript - Save data in local storage into myphpadmin's database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

hye.. im trying to create a quiz game but now im stuck and already spend hours to try transferring local storage data into database but still the data can't be recorded in database.

this is my js code:

```
$('#start').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(quiz.is(':animated')) {  
      return false;
    }
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){    
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var score = $(this).val();
       localStorage.setItem(id, score);
    });   
  location.href = "wheel2.html";
  });
```

then, to show collected marks:

```
function displayScore() {
    var score = $('<p>',{id: 'question'});   
    var numCorrect = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
      if (selections[i] === questions[i].correctAnswer) {
        numCorrect+=10;
      }
    }
    score.append('You got ' + numCorrect + ' marks!! ');
 return score;
}
```

im also already try to use this code:

```
var xhr;
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var data = "marks" + score;
         xhr.open("POST", "marks.php", true); 
         xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                  
         xhr.send(data);
       xhr.onreadystatechange = display_data;
      function display_data() {
       if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
          if (xhr.status == 200) {
           //alert(xhr.responseText);    
        document.getElementById("suggestion").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
          } else {
            alert('There was a problem with the request.');
          }
         }
      }
```

this is my php code:

```
<?php
//provide your hostname, username and dbname
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test1";

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
//$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
$sql = "INSERT INTO participant (marks)
  VALUES ('".$_POST['marks']."')";

{
echo"<script>alert('successfully registered')</script>".'<a href="wheel2.html"> back </a>';
    header('location:wheel.html?message=success');
}
?>
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: did you get any error

Comment: nope. there is no error notification appear. i think its depends on how im arrange the location of the javascript functions because im not sure where to use the "xmlhttp request" either under function click or function displayScore

Comment: You can do more to debug this, there's an awful lot here for someone to poke through to find an error and I suspect this isn't even _all_ of it (I don't see an input[type="text"] for instance). For starters, open up dev tools and check on the "Network" tab. That will show you the HTTP request you sent to PHP, it's probably not what you expect it to be.

Comment: I have no confidence that this is a complete solution, hence my posting it as a comment, but you didn't actually run the query - you just turned it into a string. You need to execute it: `$conn->query($sql)` or something like that.

Comment: Forgot to put `=` sign  correct was `var data = "marks=" + score;`

Comment: no @Mahesh its still doesn't work. i think it must be something about the xmlhttp code which need to be placed under the handler or displayScore function.